# How to use ROW_NUMBER when grouping records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following:

```
DECLARE @items TABLE
(
    ItemId int NOT NULL,
    [Description] varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Amount money NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @items SELECT 1, 'A', 10;
INSERT INTO @items SELECT 2, 'A', 10;
INSERT INTO @items SELECT 3, 'B', 11;
INSERT INTO @items SELECT 4, 'B', 11;
INSERT INTO @items SELECT 5, 'B', 11;
INSERT INTO @items SELECT 6, 'C', 12;
INSERT INTO @items SELECT 7, 'C', 12;
INSERT INTO @items SELECT 8, 'A', 10;
INSERT INTO @items SELECT 9, 'A', 10;

SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.ItemId ORDER BY b.[Description]),
    [Description],  
    COUNT(ItemId) OVER(PARTITION BY b.ItemId),
    SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY b.ItemId)
FROM @items b
```

The result should be:

```
1, A, 4, 40
2, B, 3, 33
3, C, 2, 24
```

However the items are not being grouped.

So how to I need to use `ROW_NUMBER` to group records?

Comment: Think about what you are doing.  You are partitioning by `ItemId`, but ItemId is unique to the table, so what's the purpose of partitioning???

Comment: The `PARTITION BY` of a Window Function doesn't group the final result sets. It intermittently groups the rows in the windows you are describing. I would expect your above query to have 9 rows that essentially look like they may be the mostly the same as your original `@items`. Your `count()` and ROW_NUMBER() should return 1 for each row .

Comment: Kathi Kellenberger is an excellent resource for more information about Window Functions. (https://auntkathisql.com/2018/06/28/quick-t-sql-window-function-articles/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.Description),
       i.Description,  
       COUNT(*),
       SUM(i.Amount) 
FROM @items i
GROUP BY Description
ORDER BY Description;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/JAD27058).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use `GROUP BY` by itself you may do a subquery with two `row_number()`, something like this:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by t.[Description]), t.Description, t.cnt, t.summ
from (
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.[Description] ORDER BY b.[Description] )  rn,
    [Description],  
    COUNT(ItemId) OVER(PARTITION BY b.[Description]) cnt,
    SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY b.[Description]) summ
FROM @items b
) t where rn = 1
```

And anyway you shouldn't group data by the `ItemId` - it's a wrong way to achieve your aim